# Can anyone help out an Objective C novice?

Tags: objective-c

I feel i am totally out of my depth here, im very new to objective c but have been asked to design an iphone app as part of my uni course. I designed a sinple quiz before, but I was hoping to design a more advanced quiz game with 3 levels (each level will have a different quiz).

I dont know how to use the UIViews and I have tried a tutorial online to help me code a navigation controller. It allows gives me 3 options to go into subview 1, 2 or 3. All the subviews have the same screen though, with one label and a button.

I have 3 classes so far, RootViewController, BasicNavigationAppDelegate and SubViewOneController.

I really dont understand the code at all, im familiar with Java but this objective c is nothing like it. Could someone maybe take a minute to help out a person in distress and explain if i am doing this right by using the navigation controller to display my levels? When i check the xib interface files i dont see the button or label, or dont know where to add the quiz interface objects!! I really am confused by all this. Could anyone help?

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of folks who would like to help you with your problem, but without code, or with more specific details on the problem you're having, there's not much we can do.  Please narrow your question to the actual problem you are having.

Comment: Are there multiple views per quiz?

Comment: No, there is just one view per quiz. The main menu screen will the give the option of choosing between 3 levels (each level will have its own view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search [google](http://www.google.com) for sample source code, and see how some of the views can be handled. There are many ways you can handle a view, whether its by a UINavigationController, UITabBarController, etc. If you are new to Objective-C, then your not really going to get an answer to this question that will instruct you on what exactly to do.

[Interface Builder + View Controllers](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CGcQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.macrumors.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D538380&ei=9UIJTcgFkfqwA9KpoKAO&usg=AFQjCNFexqoyI_5y23_jMUzLjibOkUNLeg&sig2=F8DXLQTdbHdm4jA_fSMmqw)

Here's a good one for you: [View Controllers Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[(Apple's) View Controller Reference Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html)

[Some Code Samples](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fiphone-sdk-programming-book-code-samples%2F&ei=xUIJTaa4A4W2sAPN_-XYDg&usg=AFQjCNFQucsWVR_QvqNx4s8JubTOK4JlHg&sig2=8q9TrFlcycrt2r1zlUgFIw)

[Getting Started Sample Code](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.datasprings.com%2Fresources%2Farticles-information%2Fiphone-sdk-getting-started-example-code&ei=9UIJTcgFkfqwA9KpoKAO&usg=AFQjCNHmedHPqHGjhyMGlyaIIiE_XO4MIg&sig2=z55C7wW-r-0dIUbcMo9Bpg)

Comment: Ive ben checking out those links and doing sum reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for a 3 level quiz, UINavigationController is definitely an option.

if you need to find out how to use a class, in xcode, type its name, then press -alt- and double click the class name, this will bring up a short description, with two icons, one will take you to the header file, and the other to the documentation.

to add elements to the nib/xib files, you will need to open the library window, where you will find labels, buttons etc. to use a button, you will need to define an action in your header file, and hook it up in IB, to be able to interact with UIElements in your code, you want to set up outlets in the header file, and hook them up in IB.

something you need to decide on, is how you are going to present the questions, and will also depend if the answer will be true/false, multiple choice, or text entry.

if you arent familiar with obj-c and xcode, it is probably worth picking up an ebook from someone like http://www.pragprog.com. they have an iPhone one up there by Bill Dudney which is quite good(i believe he now works for apple.)

---

for the standard slide out transition you could use this.
    //you would probably want to call this something like level1NavBarItemWasPushed: instead
    - (IBAction)lvl1pushNavBarItem:(id)sender {
        //create instance of AnswersViewController class.
        AnswersViewController *level1AnswersVC= [[Level1AnswersViewController alloc] init];

```
    //pass it some kind of identifier so it can tell which quiz/question it is dealing with and pull in the answers, so that you can reuse the view
    [level1AnswersVC setAnswersObject:<<insert object dictionary here>>];

    //push the view controller onto the navigationController's view stack 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:level1AnswersVC animated:TRUE];

    //pushing it onto the view stack has given it +1 retain, so we can now release it without worrying about it disappearing prematurely.
    [level1AnswersVC release];
 }
```

---

for the page flip transition you could use this.

```
- (IBAction)lvl1pushNavBarItem:(id)sender {
    //create instance of AnswersViewController class.
    AnswersViewController *level1AnswersVC= [[Level1AnswersViewController alloc] init];

    //pass it some kind of identifier so it can tell which quiz/question it is dealing with and pull in the answers, so that you can reuse the view
    [level1AnswersVC setAnswersObject:<<insert object dictionary here>>];

    //set the current viewController as the delegate, so that it can call back to us when its done        
    level1AnswersVC.delegate = self;

    //set the modal transition style
level1AnswersVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    //show answers as modal view, which has been setup to use the page flip transition.
[self presentModalViewController:level1AnswersVC animated:YES];

    //pushing it onto the view stack has given it +1 retain, so we can now release it without worrying about it disappearing prematurely.
    [level1AnswersVC release];
 }
```

Comment: Its mainly the UIView and Navigation controller ive been struggling with. I have designed a working quiz before, but just using the main rootview window. My problem is trying to put this quiz on 3 different views, with different questions and answers. The navigationController i have done using an online tutorial takes me to these 3 subviews but i dont understand the code. Im reading some stuff online, hopefully i figure it.

Comment: you don't understand any of it? or are there specific chunks? if you post some of the code you don't understand, i can explain it to you.

Comment: I got the views to work and am using navigation controller, although i dont think im using it right:- (IBAction)lvl1pushNavBarItem:(id)sender {
 
 [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context: NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self cache:YES];
    [view2 removeFromSuperview];
 [self addSubview:view1];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
    
}

Comment: I have added two alternate ways of doing this above, which make use of the viewController/navigationController to do most of the heavy lifting.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html has lots of details on view controllers, you should read this in depth, understanding how it fits together conceptually will make things way easier down the road.

Comment: Do u know how to reference a uiview? I have 2, called view1 and view2. In one of my classes im trying to set label texts of labels in those views but they arent working. When i try:               [view2.lvl1ButtonNext setTitle:@"Next" forState: UIControlStateNormal];           I get an error: "member not part of a structure or union." Any ideas how to reference the uiviews?

Comment: if you have declared the view in your current header, and the button in the view's header, you should be able to access them like this: [[view2 lvl1Button] setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlState]; alternatively you can do this: view2.button.titleLabel.text=@"text";
The way you are calling it should work, as long as you have declared a property for the button, ie in view2.h you have the line @property(non-atomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button; and in view2.m you have @synthesize button

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ***[Head First iPhone Development: A Learner's Guide to Creating Objective-C Applications for the iPhone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596803540)***. Within a few chapters you'll know everything you need to build this app *and* you'll actually understand what you're doing.

*(I don't know the authors or the publisher, I just think it's a great book for quickly getting up to speed.)*

Comment: Lookin at sum customer reviews and its only been gettin 3/6 stars, so its kinda put me off. Found sum stuff online ive been reading through though. Its mainly the UIView and Navigation controller ive been struggling with. But thank you for your suggestion.